# How to delete everything after special charcter in each column in Excel document and divide two words from one cell to two separate cells?

Tags: excel, divide

I have excel document with one column. It looks like this:

```
 car /VIj+
 car, cars /VIj-
 home, homes /VKjsah+
 homeless, homeless /VKjsbh+
.
.
.
```

And I need to delete everything after symbol / including symbol / in each column. Then I need to divide cells with two words in to the separate cells and delete symbol , which is between words. Can somebody help me?

Comment: are these columns one next to other or each is in separate sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your data are in single column and there are empty columns right to the data column. If so you could run this code for selected range containing data:

```
Sub Solution()
    Dim tmpArr
    Dim Cell As Range
    For Each Cell In Selection.Cells
        tmpArr = Split(Split(Cell, "/")(0), ",")
        Cell.Resize(1, 1 + UBound(tmpArr)) = tmpArr
    Next
End Sub
```

The following picture presenting results of the macro.

[image]

Comment: If I run this macro I get error message Run-time error 9, Subscript out of range and row tmpArr.... is highlited. Where is the problem? It can be that my excel document have more than 100 000 columns?

Comment: It works but not for each column. I have to run this macro for every 5000 cells for example. But thank you very match for your solution.

Comment: there could be some problems depending on set of data you have. But it works for sample data you provided in question. Therefore I also made some assumptions at the beginning. Happy I helped :)